# Search inside jScrollPane?

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

Without jscrollpane, a search from firefox (ctrl+f) on a page with a limited height div with overflow:auto, reach words that are not visibles. With jscrollpane, words are also found but don't scroll directly to them. Is there a way to have the same behaviour ?

Try to search Maecenas in the example page (with and without javascript, to see the difference)
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html

Answer (score 0):

You have `.jspContainer{ overflow: hidden; }` in jquery.jscrollpane.css

If you switch to `overflow: auto` you get what you want.

Of course now you have the ugly scrollbar you did not want in the first place.

I tried to get rid of them by making the CSS different. But unfortunately jsScrollPane does not scroll actually, but sets the top position of the absolute positioned `.jspPane`. 
So I cannot get rid of `position: relative` in the `jspContainer`, which I wanted

If you could reprogramm jsScrollPane to use style scrollTop instead of top. It would be possible.

Comment: it looks like JScrollPane already uses `$(selector).scrollTop` and `scrollLeft`

Comment: Not on my computer. The link in the question looked at in Chrome: It uses top and left.

Comment: odd, I'm looking at the unminified version, every time it actually sets a value it calls `scrollTop()` and `scrollLeft()`.  It does call `top` and `left` a couple times on "position" and "offset" objects, but those wouldn't have a scrollTop/scrollLeft would they?

Comment: I don't mean scrollTop, scrollLeft as functions. scrollTop and scrollLeft are attributes of DOM elements, which change if you scroll. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop

Comment: Inspect the CSS values with Firebug. You will see, the CSS values top and left are changing